# Intersection of an open interval and a half-closed interval.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been struggling on a question that seems simple but I can't get my head around it.

I need to find the intersection of:

$(-\infty, 0 ) \cap [0, \infty)$

and I am struggling to understand why the answer is the set {0} as compared to the empty set. I tried the number line method but I feel I'm missing something important.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: 0 Is in the second but it is not in the first. In the first there is no $x>0$ and in the second there is no $x<0$ so no element can be in both sets.

Comment: Precisely, I think then that the answer given to me itself must be wrong. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The answer is the empty set.